Tangent Vector, Principal normal vector, Binormal vector, and Torsion
So I'm trying to fully grasp how all these relate. My current understanding is that the tangent vector describes the direction in which the curve is going/curving. Meanwhile, the principal norm is essentially the derivative of the tangent vector describing the rate at which the tangent vector is changing direction. Leaving the Binormal vector which is the cross product of the two previous vectors indicating the plane in which they reside? Also, with regards to torsion, from what I understand it is the rate at which the curve twists? So would it also be correct to say it is essentially the rate at which the plane is twisting in space. Since the tangent and principal normal vector are part of that plane.

Which plane? Once you specify that, yes, you are correct.

The plane spanned by the tangent and normal vector?  Also, thank you.

Yes, since the rate of change of the binormal vector (which is the normal to the osculating plane) is torsion.
